# Telegram Bot Inline Keyboard Not Showing PHP

Tags: php, telegram-bot

I'm a newbie to programming and Telegram bot. This is the first time I post a question here.

I'm trying to make an inline keyboard with PHP, following a tutorial. I have checked multiple times with the tutorial. I have also searched for hours for other examples. But so far, I can't find any solution. And I don't know what went wrong.

I have a function:

```
function inlinekeyboard($button, $cid, $text) {
    if(strpos($text, "\n")){
        $text = urlencode($text);
    }
    $inlineKey = ["incline_keyboard" => $button];
    $inlineKey = json_encode($inlineKey);
    apiRequest("sendMessage?chat_id=".$cid."&text=".$text."&parse_mode=Markdown&reply_markup=".$inlineKey);
}
```

And I want to create an inline keyboard with this function:

```
$button = [[
    ["text" => "Bottun 1", "url" => "https://www.aaa.com"],
    ["text" => "Bottun 2", "url" => "https://www.bbb.com"]
]];
inlinekeyboard($button, $cid, "click to choose");
```

I have also tried:

```
$button[] = array(array("text" => "Bottun 1", "url" => "https://www.aaa.com"),);
$button[] = array(array("text" => "Bottun 2", "url" => "https://www.bbb.com"),);
inlinekeyboard($button, $cid, "click to choose");
```

But none of them work.
the Bot just replied, "click to choose". No inline keyboard is shown.

Can anyone help me understand what was wrong with it?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. It seems that you have a typo in your code. Inside the function change `incline_keyboard` to `inline_keyboard`

Comment: As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Wow~Thanks, @AliPadida. This is such an embarrassing typo... -_-!!

Comment: Thanks, @UlrichEckhardt. I will do that!

Comment: We all face such mistakes after a long time of coding. Have fun!